# Quickly enumerate domain users in remote trusted domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

We have a situation where application code running on a server in one domain needs to list the users in another domain. Let's call the domains "PRODUCTION" and "CORPORATE" -- this code needs to run in PRODUCTION and interact with PRODUCTION resources, but there is a particular flow in which it needs to allow the user to select a member of CORPORATE\Domain Users (well, technically a more specific group, but that's a technicality). CORPORATE's domain controllers are all located remotely from the PRODUCTION servers, accessible over a VPN that is reasonably fast but a far cry from local. I have been having difficulty finding a way to efficiently list the members of the CORPORATE group.

I have tried various APIs, most recently the PowerShell ActiveDirectory module, which I suspect is built on top of System.DirectoryServices in the .NET Framework. The following command runs on a machine in the CORPORATE domain and on the CORPORATE LAN directly in several seconds:

```
Get-ADGroup "Domain Users" | Get-ADGroupMember
```

However, if I go to a machine in PRODUCTION, for which the CORPORATE DC is remote, the equivalent command:

```
Get-ADGroup -Server CORPORATEDC "Domain Users" | Get-ADGroupMember
```

...takes over 10 minutes to complete.

The result set has 1288 elements in it.

Is there some faster way to get the group members? The performance characteristics feel like it is setting up a remote iterator and then incurring a separate network round-trip (or perhaps several) for each individual element. Is there an API that can return the results in a single round-trip?

I ultimately want to do this from C# code and was just using PowerShell to proof out concepts. I am not opposed to using a native P/Invoke or COM API if it offers the functionality I need.

Comment: I suspect you're correct in that the PowerShell cmdlets are using System.DirectoryServices. Ten minutes seems slow, but as you said you're going over a VPN into another network. There are lots of variables at play, most of which we couldn't begin to troubleshoot.

Comment: An update, after some back-and-forth with the server admins, I've discovered that `Get-ADUser` with an appropriate search base and a wildcard filter can retrieve the same records in about 2 seconds. So, it _is_ possible! I just need to determine what the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet is using under the hood.

Comment: And the answer to that is that it is using Active Directory Web Services, which appears to be something Microsoft invented for the purpose and has not documented particularly well. Sigh.